# Facebook error while linking: how to fix?

Tags: facebook, twitter

How do you disable this? I just created a page on FB (today), and I got this error as I was trying to link my twitter account to the page.

"ERROR:This endpoint has been deprecated.To temporarily reenable it,you may disable the "august_2012" platform migration. It will be disable permanently on August 1,2012."

Comment: You can get help from Facebook for user / account / site problems at https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=220217228006012 - this is not the correct forum for those questions (see http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq#questions  for more information)

Answer (score 0):

It's a twitter issue. The twitter app for facebook has not been updated to the new iFrames framework, and still relies on the FBML framework. Thus we'll have to wait till the app is updated. The solution provided above only works if the developer of twitter app enables that option. You can read more here: http://technoritz.com/post/28770685151/this-is-not-a-facebook-problem-it-is-a-twitter

Here is the official response from twitter: https://twitter.com/Support/statuses/231138059071156225