# Linking Twitter account to new company page on FB returns error message

Tags: twitter

I created a company page on FB a few days ago linked to my personal account, but I got this error as I was trying to link my Twitter account to the company page. The Twitter account linked fine to my personal account page, but gave the following error when I tried to link to company page...

"ERROR:This endpoint has been deprecated.To temporarily reenable it,you may disable the "august_2012" platform migration. It will be disable permanently on August 1,2012."

I saw a post about this problem on Stack Overflow at [Facebook error while linking: how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769449/facebook-error-while-linking-how-to-fix)

But I didn't understand the fix suggested by Igy:

"You can get help from Facebook for user / account / site problems at facebook.com/help/?page=220217228006012 - this is not the correct forum for those questions (see facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq#questions for more information) – Igy 13 hours ago"

I went to both the links Igy provided but couldn't find anything having to do with this issue.

Sorry I am not a coder. In the next life. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The reply is saying that you can get help for your Facebook user, Facebook account or Facebook site at the link provided. This website is not for general Facebook help which you have. Please visit the link and you can find the answer you are looking for by searching there.